# I am popping a New Web Deploy Permissions Error

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

My first publish attempt (for a site that I've been publishing for months with no problem) post-.NET 6 is generating this error.

Unable to perform the operation ("Create File")  for the specified directory ("C:\inetpub\ECM2\wwwroot\Identity\lib\bootstrap\LICENSE")

I'm publishing as *the* Administrator and, as indicated, this has been working for months.

Comment: Try to check the security of LICENSE folder. Make sure the application pool and IUSR has the full control permission so that application can create file.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  I'm using web deploy from VS to an Azure App Service, changing the setting 'Remove additional files at destination' to true fixed it.  It's found in the settings for the publishing profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination was to tick the 'remove files' box as well.  This allowed me to publish the site but it also had a follow-on effect (for anyone else with this issue).

I didn't consider that this would also delete the web.config file, the absence of which caused a very ambiguous 403 error.

Reconstituting web.config on the server took care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error I received as well. I clicked on "Remove extra files" in the publisher profile and the error went away.

[image]